# Access epoch from date field in groovy script in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

My orignal question is here 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/access-the-epoch-of-the-date-type-doc-in-groovy-script/53129

I need to access the stored millis(as in index) of the date in groovy script. Is this possible

**Orignal Question**
As per my understanding and from here [[understanding how elasticsearch stores dates internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341715/understanding-how-elasticsearch-stores-dates-internally]) ([understanding how elasticsearch stores dates internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341715/understanding-how-elasticsearch-stores-dates-internally)) elastic search stores the date internally as epoch format. Now consider I need to access this epoch in groovy script and out doc date format is date_optional_time. Now when I try to access it in groovy script it gives me the formatted date(as on the time of input). Is there a way to access the epoch time here.
I have come up with three thoughts
1) Convert the doc value to date and get millis in script,
2) Create a new field with copy_to that stores the date as epoch format
3)//or if possible directly access the epoch. but how?

Can some body guide me on this.I need epoch because I need to update some other field on basis of the epoch

e.g 
Consider a mapping like this

```
   {
       "createdDate": {
                      "type": "date",
                      "store": true,
                      "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                      }
       "modifiedDate": {
                      "type": "date",
                      "store": true,
                      "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                      }
      "daysINBetween" : {
        "type" : "long"
    }
    ,
    }
```

Now I need to run a script that stores `(createdDate.millis - modifiedDate.millis) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`. I don't want to create a new object of date each time, that's why I am trying to access epoch in script

Comment: If I'm not mistaken either `doc.createdDate.value` or `doc.createdDate.date.millis` should get you the epoch time.

Comment: @Val If I am right `doc` is only accessible in script field. But I need it in script in update by query

Comment: `doc` is accessible in all scripting contexts, try it out.